# Someone's something

Tags: riddle

I'm someone's something, and I'm often quite puzzled,

I now need your help to become less befuddled.

You can do it quite fast, or even with some weird odors !

As soon as you're right, I'll show my true colors.

---

*Who am I ?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> A Rubik's cube

I'm someone's something, and I'm often quite puzzled,

> Rubik's cubes are usually mixed up

I now need your help to become less befuddled. You can do it quite fast, or even with some weird odors ! As soon as you're right, I'll show my true colors.

> You solve it and the colours are in the right place

Comment: somehow i feel that the line about odors are a hint to rot13(nytbevguz) , but I cant connect the dots

Comment: Correct ! Just to complete the clues : 
- The actual spelling is (r13)Ehovx'f phor, which explains the title
- Odors refer to people (r13) fbyivat gurz jvgu gurve srrg

Comment: @Soltius Thank you! Nice riddle; It was really fun solving :)